# Calculate True Anomaly in future

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

I am working on a little orbit simulation game. I already got it working previously. But I am changing my system up a bit on how I calculate it. Previously I calculated the true anomaly with time and offset to periapsis. And now i want to change the offset to continuously updated true anomaly. But I cant get the thing to work. Please help me how I can calculate the True Anomaly in delatime seconds in the future, given Semi Major Axis and Eccentricity, and True Anomaly. Also I already tried calculating the mean anomaly from the true anomaly, and add mean motion to it, but i reversed the orbit, and made the apoapsis the fastest point. Please help me!

Comment: The formulas for computing true anomaly from mean anomaly (or at least approximate it) are fairly basic and you should be able to google it.